# ISO 9141, LIN Bus, K-Line compatibility

Tags: automotive, transceiver, lin

I'm designing an automotive scan tool. For now, I'm studying about ISO 9141 and LIN Bus physical layer compatibility. I have a legacy hardware that uses L9637 to perform ISO 9141, through K-Line, but I want to add LIN capabilities in the new hardware.

Does ISO 9141 and LIN BUs use K-line the same way ? I mean, can I use L9637 as a transceiver in a LIN BUS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your comment while looking for questions I had myself about ISO-9141-2.

ISO9141 and LINbus are very similar standards, in fact the LINBus standard specifies that it uses a modified ISO 9141 transceiver (how it's modified I don't know).  From what I understand K-Line is just a different name for ISO 9141.

The L9637 I think will work but there could be edge cases where it won't.  I you can, chat with the manufacturer's technical support personnel.  I think I've seen LINBus devices using L9637 but I can't be sure.

This project:http://www.obddiag.net/allpro.html is using a LINBus transceiver for communications with ISO9141 so it must work to some extent.

Hope that helps.